# SQL -- Join on a range of decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using Microsoft SQL Server and I have the following tables:

`dbo.student`:

```
+-----------+------------+
| StudentID | Percentage |
+-----------+------------+
| 100       | 0.75       |
| 101       | 0.82       |
| 102       | 0.95       |
| 103       | 0.59       |
+-----------+------------+
```

`dbo.GradeMaster`:

```
+---------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| GradeID | Grade | PercentageRangeBottom | PercentageRangeTop |
+---------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| 1       | A     | 0.91                  | 1                  |
| 2       | B     | 0.81                  | 0.9                |
| 3       | C     | 0.71                  | 0.8                |
| 4       | D     | 0.61                  | 0.7                |
| 5       | F     | 0                     | 0.6                |
+---------+-------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

I am trying to generate a report which will spit out a letter grade and a student ID. I don't want to use a giant case statement with hardcoded ranges in case anyone ever decides to update the ranges in `dbo.GradeMaster` (for example, an A becomes from .85 - 1).  What is the best way to join on these two tables? I thought about also creating a function to figure out letter grade but I can't think of the smartest way to go about that. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.  This is what I would expect the report to look like.

```
+-----------+-------+
| StudentID | Grade |
+-----------+-------+
| 100       | C     |
| 101       | B     |
| 102       | A     |
| 103       | F     |
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: Use [Between](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php) operator.

Comment: You can use the `BETWEEN` operator to join both tables so you the join condition will be like `ON Student.Percentage BETWEEN GradeMaster.PercentageRangeBottom AND GradeMaster.PercentageRageTop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT Student.StudentId, GradeMaster.Grade 
FROM Student 
    INNER JOIN GradeMaster ON
        Student.Percentage BETWEEN GradeMaster.PercentageRangeBottom AND GradeMaster.PercentageRangeTop
```

Instead of joining directly field-to-field you can use `BETWEEN` or similar logic to perform the join

Comment: that's perfect. Thanks. It didn't occur to me to use a between on a join like that.